# Correctly applying the "rule of five" to a RAII socket wrapper

Tags: c++, socket, tcp, posix, raii

I was trying to create a simple RAII wrapper with rule of 5 for a TCP POSIX socket. My aim was to try learn how to apply rule of five in different situations, but this one was somehow tricky.

```
class tcp_socket {
public:
    tcp_socket() {
        _s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    }

    tcp_socket(const tcp_socket& other) = delete;
    tcp_socket& operator=(const tcp_socket& other) = delete;

    tcp_socket(tcp_socket&& other) noexcept {
        _s = other._s;
        other._s = -1;
    }

    tcp_socket& operator=(tcp_socket&& other) noexcept {
        if (this != &other) {        
            _s = other._s;
            other._s = -1;
        }
        return (*this);
    }

    ~tcp_socket() {
        close(_s);
    }

private:
    int _s = -1;
};
```

In this class, I like to create socket in constructor and close it in destructor, a logical RAII approach. But I noticed closing socket in destructor creates a lot of side effects for writing other 4 routines of rule of five.

**Move constructor/assignment:**

As you see, I use `other._s = -1;` in move constructor/assignment. Because if I don't, when the moved object deletes, it will also close my socket in moved-to object. I think this will solve my problem, because when moved object will be destroyed, it will try to close `-1` file descriptor which is an error, but will not ruin anything.

**Copy constructor/assignment:**

As you see, the only method that I could think of for copy constructor/assignment is deleting them. Because at first I thought to use `dup()` to duplicate file descriptor for copying, but if I do so, operations on one one instance (for example `shutdown()`) will affect another instance.

What do you think about this class? Do you think if this class does provide a simple RAII with correct rule of five or I need to adjust it somehow? Is it possible to write Copy constructor/assignment somehow or it is not logical to provide them?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with deleting the copy constructor and assignment operator if they don't make sense.  The C++ stream classes do the same thing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The only situation for copy constructor/assignment that I think of is when you was to use single socket in for example multiple thread. You want to pass socket for example in a visitor approach to other classes and use it in other classes. SO copy constructor/assignment is useful, but I really could not find a proper way to provide them.

Comment: @SombreroChicken the main reason I posted it here was copy constructor/assignment and if there is a way to provide them.

Comment: @Afshin in that case you need something like `tcp_socket_ref` which act as an observer to the socket. Much like you can use raw pointers to observe the value of a `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @Afshin -- Change the word "socket" to "stream" in your comment, and you will see yourself in the same boat as C++ streams.

Comment: As an aside, move-assignment is badly broken. Make it an unconditional straight swap.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I thought of something like that myself too. So you think we need to do reference counting in this case too?

Comment: @Deduplicator why move assignment is broken?

Comment: @Afshin depends on what you want. Do you want shared ownership or unique ownership?

Comment: @Afshin it's broken because it leaks the `other`'s socket. It should be a swap.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: While a swap has elegance to it, I think it's somewhat inappropriate for one socket wrapper to infest another socket wrapper with something that requires a potentially failing system call. I say "clean up your own mess".

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I have seen  arguments that say sometimes using swap for move is not a good idea. because to does too many assignments which will be not necessary.

Comment: @Afshin in this case, your move assigement leaks a socket. If `other._s` is not `-1`, you **always leak**. Test it yourself and you'll see. The idiomatic fix is swap, and it so happen that it's also the most effecient. Your move constructor is okay though.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: You're right (and HolyBlackCat said so too) but there is more than one alternative.

Comment: Unrelated: after `_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);`, the code should test `_s` to make sure a socket was acquired. If it wasn't, this would be a fabulous place to throw an exception.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot yea, I got it. I had that memory leak because I forgot to use `close(_s);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are good questions!

#### 1. You should indeed have the copy constructor & assignment operator deleted.

The "rule of five" tells you to specifically define a copy c'tor and assignment operator - but it doesn't tell you that you have to make them public. It is a perfectly valid choice to decide to *not* allow your object to be copied or non-move-assigned - only moved. An example of this: [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

It's also what I would recommend in your case, because:

1. Like you said, duplicating a file descriptor is weird and unexpected.
2. It's not obvious to the user of your class what the copy behavior *should* be.
3. There don't seem to be - AFAICT - common scenarios in which you would *copy*, rather than move or pass by *reference*, a TCP socket.

#### 2. Consider using `std::optional` to indicate "no valid value" or "missing" or "none"

In C (and the C system call bindings on Unix-like systems), it is a convention to use the -1 value for an invalid/missing file descriptor is a convention. We know that the `int` type is actually larger than the actual space of possible file descriptor values, so we use a junk value, which we assume the OS never uses, to indicate "no valid value". Now, this works fine; and you could choose to, say, define a static class constant:

```
static constexpr const int no_file_descriptor { -1 };
```

and then write:

```
close(_s);
_s = other._s;
other._s = no_file_descriptor;
```

<sub>As @HolyBlackCat suggests, you must get `_s` to be closed somehow. You could also just swap the two descriptors, but I find that to contradict the element of least surprise.</sub>

but you might want to consider the more general (though less space-efficient) solution, which is the [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) type template. It is intended for exactly your case: Either holding some value of type `T` (in your case, `int`), or holding some indication of "no value". Using an optional, you could write:

```
close(_s.get());
_s = other._s;
other._s = std::nullopt;
```

You'll still need to write your move assignment and move construction code, unfortunately (thanks @CassioRenan for noticing these are both necessary).

#### Other suggestions

3. Don't use a plain `int`; either find a type definition of a file descriptor from some library you're using, or if you have no definition to borrow, have `using file_descriptor = int;` or `using file_descriptor_index = int`.
4. `_s` is a bad member name. Use something more explicit, e.g. `descriptor_index_` or `posix_descriptor_index_`.
5. Always check the return value of library/system calls! And handle errors.

#### The modified code

```
class tcp_socket {
protected:
    void close_if_neccessary() {
       constexpr auto socket_close_failed { -1 };
        if (descriptor_index_.has_value()) { 
            auto retval = close(descriptor_index_.value()); 
            if (retval == socket_close_failed) { 
               // throw something here, e.g.:
               // throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category(), "close()");
            }
    };
public:
    using file_descriptor_index = int;

    tcp_socket() : descriptor_index_() { 
       constexpr auto socket_creation_failed { -1 };
       auto retval = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
       if (retval == socket_creation_failed) { 
           // throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category(), "socket()");
       }
       descriptor_index = retval;
    };

    tcp_socket(const tcp_socket& other) = delete;
    tcp_socket& operator=(const tcp_socket& other) = delete;
    tcp_socket& operator=(tcp_socket&& other) noexcept {
        if (other.descriptor_index_ != descriptor_index_) {
            close_if_neccessary();
            descriptor_index_ = other.descriptor_index_;
            other.descriptor_index_ = std::nullopt;
        }
        return this;
    };
    tcp_socket(tcp_socket&& other) noexcept :
        descriptor_index_(other.descriptor_index_) 
    {
        other.descriptor_index = std::nullopt;
    }
    ~tcp_socket() { 
        // You might want to wrap this in a try-catch, since
        // destructors shouldn't throw. Otherwise you're risking
        // a double-exception and immediate program termination.
        close_if_necessary(); 
    }

protected:
    std::optional<file_descriptor_index> descriptor_index_;
};
```

See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12171377/1593077) about the weird exception code in the comments:

Comment: if I use `std::optional`, I need to check and if it has value then close it is destructor,isn't it?

Comment: @Afshin: Yes, essentially: `if descriptor_index_.has_value() { close(descriptor_index); }`

Comment: I would advise against `std::optional`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: It's not essential to use it, but - why would you advise against?

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica because there is a complete subset of a value an int can take to represent a unix socket. `-1` is the value used to contain the *no  socket* in case of errors. I would personally not transform the value representation of what an API returns. I may not know someday `-2` could be used for something else. Also, it's a bit like `std::unique_ptr`. It doesn't contain an optional pointer. Rather, the `nullptr` value denotes the *not owner* value.

Comment: I somehow agree with Guillaume more with not using optional in this specific case.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: There is, but why is that an issue? Are you out of bytes? Do you expect there to be a hundreds of thousands of RAII sockets making the space-saving meaningful? As for `std::unique_ptr` - it can get away with it, maybe, because pointers traditionally have `nullptr` as a meaningful value. Having said that - allowing for a "null socket" is as simple as adding a default constructor to my code.

Comment: @Afshin: You're thinking in C terms. You should not explore these minor hacks unless it really gives you some benefit other than feeling clever. It's much better to have simpler, shorter, code with less information to remember.

Comment: Just noticed something else: If you use the move constructor by doing `tcp_socket a; tcp_socket b(std::move(a))`, you end up closing the same socket twice. This happens because when moving a `std::optional`, the moved-from `optional` will still contain a value (except that it will be a *moved-from* value). My take from this is that `std::optional` is really not a great choice for this specific problem.

Comment: @CássioRenan: Oh, man! That's so annoying. I somehow had it in my head that moving from an optional actually clears it. Thanks again.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica "It's much better to have simpler, shorter, code with less information to remember.", and that is what you did in this code???

Comment: @E.Vakili: The lengthening of my code are mostly not due to the use of `std::optional` - it's longer names, error handling avoiding double-close's, comments... but ok, fair point still.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Adding `std::optional` does not add any benefits to the solution except loss of efficiency, readability, and ... It's not a C++ point of view as you claim. C++ aims at bringing strong abstraction alongside the efficiency. Don't pay for what you don't need.

Answer (score 6):

There's one major problem with the code:

**Your move assignment is broken.**

You forgot to `close(_s)` before overwriting it with `other._s`.

To avoid this kind of problems, I suggest using the copy-and-swap idiom. It makes writing a `operator=` a no-brainer in most cases:

```
tcp_socket &operator=(tcp_socket other) noexcept // Note the lack of `&&`.
{
    std::swap(_s, other._s);
    return *this;
}
```

If you decide to do this, you also need to remove `tcp_socket& operator=(const tcp_socket& other) = delete;` to prevent it from conflicting with this operator.

---

Additionally...

**You shouldn't do `close(-1)`.**

Moving an object sets `_s` of the original object to `-1`.

`close(-1)` is not a no-op. (It sets `errno` to 'bad file descriptor'.) Thus the destructor should do

```
if (_s != -1)
    close(_s);
```

**It would be a good idea to have a way to create a 'null' `tcp_socket` instance.**

Instances of `tcp_socket` don't necessarily own sockets. By moving from an instance, or make it 'null' (i.e. it no longer owns a socket).

IMO, it would make sense to have a way to directly create 'null' intstances.

I wouldn't open the socket in `socket()`, and create a separate constructor that does open one.

**You don't *have* to explicitly delete the copy constructor and assignment operator.**

Declaring a move constructor or assignment operator causes both the constructor and assignment operator to be implicitly deleted.

Whether or not you *should* delete them explicitly (for extra clarity) is a different question.

Comment: I would +1 you for the first two suggestions, but -1 you for the third one. It would not be a good idea to be able to create a 'null' TCP socket. That kind of flies in the face of the RAII approach. Now, you could argue that perhaps RAII is not a good approach for sockets, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: if you provide move assignment in the way you did, you practically provide copy assignment too.isn't it? so I think it is better to add `&&` to provide move only. and yea, I missed `close(_s);`, I should have not made that mistake.

Comment: @Afshin If you had a non-deleted copy constructor, then yes, this assignment operator would act as a copy assignment too (another reason why copy-and-swap is so good). But since your copy constructor is deleted, it doesn't. If you added `&&` here, you'd need to do `other._s = -1` manually. (Having `operator=` swap objects is not a good idea.)

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Let's agree to disagree. :) From my experience, it's extremely convenient (and it would be even more convenient if creating a socket required some parameters, preventing `tcp_socket` from being default-constructible otherwise). And, after all, that's what `std::fstream` does.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It _is_ extremely convenient - but in the same way that having a null pointer is convenient. The inconvenience forces you to not whip these objects into existence until you really need to. Remember you can always use `std::optional<tcp_socket>`, and that's your "null socket" right there.

Comment: You made a mistake. since I need to provide deleted copy assignment, you **must** add `&&` to your move assignment. I just tested and if we don't we get `use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous` error which is logical.

Comment: @Afshin Huh, you're right. But rather than adding `&&`, you can simply remove the deleted copy assignment. It will be implicitly deleted anyway, and an implicitly deleted copy assignment doesn't seem to cause such conflicts.

Comment: But If I remove explicitly deleted copy assignment and `&&`, code will not be efficient because both move constructor and move assignment will be called(not sure why move constructor will be called in this case, but testing so I'm sure). So still adding `&&` is better.

Comment: @Afshin More function calls doesn't necessarily mean slower code, the only way to know for sure is to benchmark it. I wouldn't expect any noticeable slowdown, especially in release builds. The reason why I prefer the `&&`-less version is because it's easier to write.

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have said, use swap to get assignment correct, and don't close already-closed descriptors.

Some minor style nitpicks to add:

- Use initializers in preference to assignment in the constructors.
- There's no need to name the arguments to the deleted copy methods.
- Remove the redundant parens from `return *this;`.
- Consider a public `close()` method, for users that care about handling errors.

In contrast to einpoklum, I like your choice of invalid file descriptor (-1); we don't need the overhead of `std::optional` when a clear invalid value is available.  I do recommend giving it a name, though.

## My version

```
#include <utility>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          /* required on pre-POSIX BSD platforms */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

class tcp_socket
{
public:
    tcp_socket()
        : s{::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)}
    {
    }

    tcp_socket(const tcp_socket&) = delete;
    void operator=(const tcp_socket&) = delete;

    tcp_socket(tcp_socket&& other) noexcept
        : s{other.s}
    {
        other.s = null_socket;
    }

    tcp_socket& operator=(tcp_socket&& other) noexcept
    {
        return swap(other);
    }

    int close() {
        return ::close(s);
    }
    
    ~tcp_socket()
    {
        if (s != null_socket) {
            // note: errors are ignored!
            close();
        }
    }

private:
    static constexpr int null_socket = -1;

    int s;

    tcp_socket& swap(tcp_socket& other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(s, other.s);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

## Future directions

You might need a `udp_socket` before long.  It's probably a good idea to create a `socket` base class with protected constructor so that the RAII is managed in a single-responsibility class and the protocol-specific part is in relevant subclasses:

```
class socket
{
protected:
    socket(int fd)
        : s{fd}
    {
    }

public:
    // ...
};

class tcp_socket : public socket
{
public:
    tcp_socket()
        : socket{::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)}
    {
    }
};
```